# Change font size on WordPress blog excerpt only with inline CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, blogs

I am having a lot of trouble changing the font size for my blog excerpt only.
You can view source or live at www.780webdesign.com if need. You can see how tiny the font is. I am using inline CSS. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a self contained example for the question? Otherwise it won't be much use to others as your source changes going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.shortcode_blog .blog_excerpt p {font-size: 14px;}
```

Add this to your css, with the value being whatever size you are after.

Comment: Do I need to add '!important'? If so, how do I add that?

Comment: it should work as just the code above. If not then: `{font-size: 14px !important;}`